# Can a Jew lose their Jewish Status?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, am-yisrael-jewish-nation

Can a Jew lose their status as being a Jew by performing any action (example: performing idolatry, disavowing core beliefs, converting to another religion, etc)? Or once a person is a Jew then they keep this status no matter what?

And if a person would always maintain their status as a Jew (in terms of other Jews viewing that person to still be obligated to follow the commandments), then what in practice would be the significance of a Jew converting to another religion?

Comment: On the phrase "status as being a Jew" - there are many things that define and qualify one's "Jewish status" that are incidental: what "abilities" or "privileges" a person has in performing certain functions in Jewish life and law. However, the rights that one accrues are at most secondary in terms of his essential "Jewish status", which is defined by his obligation to uphold the laws of the Torah (as they pertain to him). This does not change, regardless of what a Jewish person does.

Comment: I think the second paragraph should be made into a separate question. It is very interesting, and no one has answered it here.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28158/apostate-jew-performing-mitzvahs/68347#68347

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51259/does-a-jewish-grandmother-mothers-side-really-get-one-accepted-as-a-jew

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For a person who has renounced their Judaism, it appears that while the person doesn't need to undergo a full conversion (on a Torah level), there is a custom to reaccept the Torah on some level and immerse in a mikvah before returning to the previous status. This seems to be especially true if the Jew literally worshiped idolatry. However, they are still a Jew in every sense of the word. (See https://aish.com/who-is-a-jew/) and (https://aish.com/status-of-baptized-jew/)

1. [Rambam, Hil. Mamrim 3:1-3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e303.htm): A person who doesn't believe in the Oral Torah, of his own will (ie: he was not mislead by someone) is no longer part of Israel - "כל אלו אינן בכלל ישראל"
2. [Rambam, Hil. Avodah Zarah 2:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1402.htm): A Jew who worships idolatry is like a non-Jew in all respects - ישראל שעבד עבודה זרה--הרי הוא כגוי לכל דבר
3. [Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deiah 268:12, Rema](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%97#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.99.D7.91): A Jewish apostate who performs Teshuvah (repents) does not need to immerse in a *mikvah* (in order to return to his former status, on a Torah level); on a rabbinic level he has to immerse and accept upon himself the mizvot ("דברי חברות") in front of three people.

If the person converted to another religion, there may also be procedural differences depending on what religion the person converted to (since some religions may have the status of being idolatrous, and some may not), or what they specifically did to disown their Judaism (or what beliefs they held that were against Jewish core beliefs).

Of course, this is a complicated topic with additional responsa literature, so please see a proper rabbinic authority if this is a practical issue for you.

Further reading:

- Rav Aharon Lichtenstein, Leaves of Faith: The World of Jewish Living. [Chapter 3: Brother Daniel and the Jewish Fraternity](http://books.google.com/books?id=_QshqTu9nGIC&lpg=PA363&ots=oaP4PpsPfZ&dq=leaves%20of%20faith%20lichtenstein&pg=PA57#v=onepage&q&f=false), pages 57-84.
- Wikipedia: [Who is a Jew?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_is_a_Jew%3F#Jews_who_have_practiced_another_faith)
- Yahoo Answers: [What does Halacha say about Jews who have converted to Christianity](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100427162911AAfsQJy)

Comment: +1.  You never lose the obligations of being a Jew, but you can lose the privileges by sinning in certain ways (until you do teshuva).  This is one of the reasons rabbis are traditionally reluctant to convert -- fear of creating a sinning Jew if the candidate turns out not to be committed.

Comment: To paraphrase @MonicaCellio Rambam says nothing of any obligation to immerse or reconvert. (Rather, he says that in some respects idolatrous Jews resemble non-Jews).

Answer (score 5):

While I am not qualified to answer the question directly, this is not a new question.  For some related sources, see the subject of Anusim on Wikipedia, specifically, and especially, the short section on Rabbinic Legal Opinions, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anusim#Rabbinic_legal_opinions):

> "Hakham Se‘adyá ben Maimón ibn Danan, one of the most respected
>   Sephardic Sages after the Expulsion, in the 15th century stated:
>
> Indeed, when it comes to lineage, all the people of Israel are
>   brethren. We are all the sons of one father, the rebels (reshaim) and
>   criminals, the heretics (meshumadim) and forced ones (anusim), and the
>   proselytes (gerim) who are attached to the house of Jacob. All these
>   are Israelites. Even if they left God or denied Him, or violated His
>   Law, the yoke of that Law is still upon their shoulders and will never
>   be removed from them.[4]
>
> Hakham BenSión Uziel, the Chief Sephardic Rabbi of the State of
>   Israel, stated in mid-20th c.
>
> And we still have to clarify on the (subject of) Anusím, to whom the
>   government forbids them to perform Halakhicly valid marriages, if it's
>   necessary to say that their wives must have a Get to permit them (to
>   marry another man), for the reason that, by force of the Law
>   (Hazaqáh), a man does not have intercourse for promiscuity (zenút). .
>   . (In our very case), we deal with those who converted and kept Torah
>   in secrecy and hide their religion because of the gentile
>   surveillance, we say that they do have intercourse for the sake of
>   marriage.
>
> It follows that Hakham Uziel considered anusím as Jews, because only
>   Jews can give or receive a Get, a Jewish divorce.
>
> Rabbi Moshe ben Maimon (Maimonides) stated in the Mishneh Torah Sefer
>   Shofetím, Hilekhót Mumarím 3:3
>
> But their children and grandchildren [of Jewish rebels], who,
>   misguided by their parents . . . and trained in their views, are like
>   children taken captive by the gentiles and raised in their laws and
>   customs (weghidelúhu haGoyím `al dathám), whose status is that of an
>   ’anús [one who abjures Jewish law under duress], who, although he
>   later learns that he is a Jew, meets Jews, observes them practice
>   their laws, is nevertheless to be regarded as an ’anús, since he was
>   reared in the erroneous ways of his parents . . . Therefore efforts
>   should be made to bring them back in repentance (LeFikakh rawí leHah
>   zirán biTeshubáh), to draw them near by friendly relations, so that
>   they may return to the strength-giving source, i.e., the Toráh "

Comment: Seth, do you mind making the transliteration a bit more fluid?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt, it is someone else's transliteration.

Comment: So do Bnei 'Anusim have a safek mamzerut ?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt as luck would have it, Catholicism forbids divorce to this day. Anusim who relocated to the the British Empire or Netherlands could divorce, but of course they could live openly as Jews, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Certain sins will cause a Jew to lose his status for many things, but not for marriage, divorce and children. I.e, a Jewish woman's children are always Jewish no matter what sins she's done, and they do not require conversion. However, if a person or group becomes completely disconnected from Judaism for many generations, they will completely lose their Jewish status for everything.

Comment: How many is many?

Comment: Source?????????

Answer (score 1):

Rambam gives a list of 13 foundations of the religion. At the conclusion of this list he writes:

> וכאשר יהיו קיימים לאדם כל היסודות הללו ואמונתו בהם אמתית הרי הוא נכנס
>   בכלל ישראל וחובה לאהבו ולחמול עליו וכל מה שצוה ה' אותנו זה על זה מן
>   האהבה והאחוה ואפילו עשה מה שיכול להיות מן העבירות מחמת תאותו והתגברות
>   יצרו הרע הרי הוא נענש לפי גודל מריו ויש לו חלק והוא מפושעי ישראל וכאשר
>   יפקפק אדם ביסוד מאלו היסודות הרי זה יצא מן הכלל וכפר בעיקר ונקרא מין
>   ואפיקורות וקוצץ בנטיעות וחובה לשנותו ועליו הוא אומר הלא משנאיך ה' אשנא
>   וכו (Qafih translation)
>
> And when a person upholds all these foundations, and his belief in
>   them is true, he enters into the group of Israel and it is an
>   obligation to love him, and to have compassion for him, and all that
>   Hashem commanded us regarding love and brotherhood for each other. And
>   even if he has done what can be of the sins due to his desires and the
>   overpowerment of his evil inclination, he will be punished
>   commensurate to the greatness of his rebellion but he still has a
>   portion and he is of the sinners of Israel. But when a person doubts
>   one of these foundations he has left the group, and denied God, and is
>   called a sectarian and a heretic and a cutter of shoots, and it is an
>   obligation to hate him, and of him it is said "do I not hate those who
>   hate you, Hashem?"

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7775/can-a-jew-lose-their-jewish-status/90558#comment9638_7775

Answer (score 0):

Today it is hard for a Jew to lose his status as a Jew since Rabenu Ovadia Yosef says that this generation has the status of *tinok shenishbah*.

On the other hand there are sins that have the punishment of caret, so his soul would be cut off from the Jewish people after his death.

Even though someone might maintain his status as Jew, he may gain the status of someone that can't be trusted (with food or testimony).

Comment: I don't believe that's what caret means.

Answer (score 0):

For a great article on this topic see Is a Jew Who Converts Still Jewish http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1269075/jewish/Is-a-Jew-Who-Converts-Still-Jewish.htm A brief Quote: 
"Achan has broken “My covenant that I have commanded them”—interpreted by the Talmud to mean not only one detail, but the entire covenant of Torah. Yet he remains not only a Jew, but “Israel”—the entirety of the Jewish People in a single individual.

The principle extends not only to genealogical Jews, but converts as well. In Tractate Yevamot we learn that once a person has fulfilled all the requirements of a proper conversion, he is considered “like Israel in all matters.” The Talmud explains those last words to mean that even if this convert would return to his pagan ways, “if he marries a Jewish woman, he has the same status as an apostate Jew, and they are considered married.”
Based on the above statement of the Talmud, the Jewish Code of Law rules that a marriage between a Jewish man and a Jewish woman who “convert out” is completely valid. Therefore, their children are considered Jewish and could also marry other Jews."

From my perspective, "Once a Jew Always a Jew;" because the Convert comes into the Community by vowing to uphold the 613 Mitzvoth (Commandments). Numbers 30:2
"When a man makes a vow to the LORD or takes an oath to obligate himself by a pledge, he must not break his word but must do everything he said."

If he fails to keep the Mitzvot in their entirety, he will be punished like any other Jew (except he return [repent or make tshuva] to Hashem) whereas if he keeps the mitzvot in their entirety, he will be rewarded like any other Jew.

A good source to read about converts is, *Converts and Conversion to Judaism*, by Rabbi Josef Lifland.

Comment: Could you summarize some of the contents of the linked page?

Answer (score 0):

We found in the Talmud (Yev 17a), about descendants of the lost tribes that could become a great problem:

לא זזו משם עד שעשאום נכרים גמורים

"They did not move from there before they made them [=Sages considered them] full gentiles"

Answer (score -6):

There is a concept of "cutting off from Israel". I.e Shemot 12:15. Whoever eats leaven on Passover is cut off from Israel. Such person is definitely not Jewish.
There are other similar prohibitions in the Torah. I.e Shemot 30:33, 38, Vaikra 7:20. Etc.

Comment: Karet (being cut off) doesn't mean one loses once Jewishness - it is a spiritual punishment where once neshama is cut off from Hashem, see e.g., [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1340046/jewish/Can-Someone-Be-Cut-Off-From-G-d.htm)

Comment: @mbloch Please provide Torah verses to backup your claims.

Comment: Bereshit 17:14, Shemot 12:15, Vayikra 7:20 all use karet in conjunction with *nefesh* (the soul). It is the *nefesh* which will be disconnected from Hashem, not the Jew who is not a Jew anymore. The latter is nowhere found.

Comment: @mbloch Well, if someone's soul gets disconnected, I do not think you can say that he is a Jew anymore. Also, can you explain Bereshit 9:11, Shemot 30:33, Vaikra 17:4, 9, 20:3, e.t.c Here it is used w/o soul. So meaning is clearly literal here. Whoever gets "cut off" is not a Jew anymore. That is the whole point of the punishment.

Comment: You are welcome to write and think what you want, I am just telling what the traditional explanation is for karet. No one would claim that a Jew having transgressed Shabbat (which is punishable by karet) is not a Jew anymore. B'shalom

Comment: @mbloch Sure, that is fine what tradition says. I am just saying what Written Torah says. These are clearly two different things for most people here.

Comment: [Karet](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0011_0_10755.html) is just one place explaining the purpose and meaning of Karet. The person is still "Jewish" as he would not be punished if he were not Jewish. Also teshuvah is still possible (though difficult). If it is a woman, her children would be Jewish (and the children of a female non-Jew are not Jewish).

Comment: @sabbahillel On which verses from the Torah you base your statement?

Comment: @AleksandrSigalov This is based on the mefarshim and on masechta Krisis, 5th masechta in sedr kodshim. A Jew cannot be turned into a gentile. "A Yisrael even though he sins is still a Yisrael". If he were not a Yisrael, he could not be punished for sinning as a gentile is not subject to the punishment.

Comment: @sabbahillel, Well, I guess you can't circumcise yourself back. Sure. But commitment of those sins does "cut you off from Israel". This is what Written Torah says and I do not understand why you reject simple meaning of the text. Its pretty clear. I understand it goes against your tradition but it does not change what is written in the text.