# Is it true that for one to become a Jew he has to be either born Jew or his mother is a Jew?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

I saw a video on youtube of a Jewish guy saying that no one can can be a Jew unless he is born Jew or his mother is a Jew.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7210/21

Comment: Is this not a dupe of either shaloms link or my am I a Jew question?

Comment: Please link this Youtube video to the OP, Casanova

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sentence in your question is a tautology. Someone whose mother is a Jew **is** *born a Jew*

The definition of a Jew is the first example of a recursive algorithm. That is the rule is

1. A person is Jewish if *he* has converted according to Jewish law.
2. A person is Jewish if *his* mother was Jewish according to this algorithm.

This recursive algorithm goes back to the Revelation at Sinai, when every member of the Bnai Yisrael *converted* to the worship of Hashem as a unit.

Before that the rules were different, but we do not need to go that far.

For example see [Is it possible for a Gentile to convert to Judaism?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/is-it-possible-for-a-gentile-to-convert-to-judaism) and [My great great grandmother was Jewish - am I?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34772/my-great-great-grandmother-was-jewish-am-i) which discuss this.

The source for this is discussed at  [Question 10.11: What is the origin of Matrilineal Descent?](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/judaism/FAQ/05-Worship/section-35.html)

> The Torah does not always state every law explicitly. In the case of
>   Matrilineal Descent, the practice is derived from [Deuteronomy 7: 4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9971#v=4),
>   `Because he will lead astray your son from before Me`

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that for one to become a Jew he has to be either born Jew or his mother is a Jew?

No, that is a rather false. I have no idea how this odd idea came about or how it spread. But it is not true.

Think about it why would a Jew have to convert? If he is Jewish, he wouldn't, because...he is already Jewish.

A convert is following in the footsteps of Ruth, a Moabite, a non Jew that became a Jew and foremother to King Duvid.

> I saw a video on youtube of a Jewish guy saying that no one can can be a Jew unless he is born Jew or his mother is a Jew.

That is the same thing. Jewishness only passes through the mother. But again, this is incorrect because we accept converts.