# Does halacha permit a Jew to practice Islam simultaneously?

Tags: halacha, islam

It is explained [here that a Jew cannot lose his 'Jewishness'](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7775/can-a-jew-lose-their-jewish-status), It seems from this answer that Jewishness is a genealogical status and little to do with religion. So is it possible for a Jew to practice Islam and Judaism simultaneously? Are there any examples of such? One example that comes to my mind is about the famed Sabbatai Tzevi who was a Jewish scholar who became Muslim and continued to show both Jewish and Islamic behaviors; are there any more examples?

Comment: @Ali, you brought an article that cites the *Islamic Encyclopedia* saying he was forced to convert as a child, returned at first opportunity, and sometimes dressed the part in a time of persecution.  That does not support your claim at all.  I would agree to reopening this but only if you promise here, publicly, not to try to change the question again.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Why isn't this still off-topic? I have 3 comment votes on my above comment.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think that that issue was also mitigated by my edit. It's not about status in the respective religions, only one of which we could answer for, but about whether the two sets of practice are compatible, which we can answer without being experts in Muslim doctrine.

Comment: @DoubleAA my comment upvote predates the edit.  The original question deserved to be closed.  A question about whether someone can practice another religion alongside Judaism seems on-topic here.

Comment: @IsaacMoses How do I know if Islam is ok with someone eating matza for a week?

Comment: @DoubleAA, so add "according to Judaism" (or "according to halacha")?  What *Islam* has to say about any of this isn't in scope.

Comment: @MonicaCellio How do I know if Judaism is ok with action X which is required by Islam, if I don't know what X is?

Comment: @DoubleAA ah, that's a good point.  The question would need to ask about specific practices.

Comment: maybe I am missing something. If the first pillar attests to Mohammed's being a prophet, and the practice of Judaism would deny this, then one cannot be a practicing member of both.

Comment: This question appears to have been converted into an expanding soapbox. I recommend editing it down to the simple on-topic question at its core that is addressed in the existing answer, re-opening, and locking. (Ping @MonicaCellio last mod on record here)

Answer (score 8):

The [two](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28694/5) [questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7775/5) that are nearly duplicates of this discuss whether a person is considered from the perspective of Halachah to be Jewish if he converts to another religion, and what the person's status is generally.  But they don't, IMO, really address this specific problem.

Here's the short answer: No.

Here's the more complex answer: No. Unless you mean is it *physically* possible for a Jew to practice another religion, in which case, obviously, a person has free will to do what he pleases. But he will be sinning.  You see, just because Judaism does not acknowledge a person's conversion to another religion (ie., Judaism views that person as being a repeat and regular sinner and violator of Jewish law), that does not mean there is any particular recourse.

Shabetai Tzevi is universally regarded by Jews the world over as a heretic and sinner. He also, incidentally, regarded himself as the Messiah, and most of his followers did too, until he started acting all weird - converting to Islam being the final straw for the few who still hung on to hope that the Messiah had arrived.

In other words, sure, a person *could* be a Jew who totally violates every Jewish precept, whether that be because the person just doesn't care or because the person converted to another religion, and yes, that person would, technically, still be considered a Jew. But ***no***, such practice is ***not*** allowed, sanctioned, or tolerated, and ***certainly not recognized***.  No "dual-citizenship" here.

Comment: This post has been locked inspite of being ontopic

Comment: @Ali The question was locked because you don't know when to quit. You asked a question. I answered it. Changing the question because you don't like the answer is bad form. If you have a different question, one that is not a differently worded  dupe of this one, you are welcome to ask it.

Comment: -1. The Koran and Torah are theologically compatible (28:48-50), so saying "No" multiple times doesn't really answer the question being posed unless you've got some evidence to provide.

Comment: @CarlMasens I'm not sure if you're serious or trolling here.  Citing the Quran to prove a question about Judaism to a Jewish group doesn't accomplish anything.  See Monica's comment here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28825/does-halacha-permit-a-jew-to-practice-islam-simultaneously/28826?noredirect=1#comment70315_28825

Comment: The question of whether the Koran and Torah are compatible is a question about the Koran and Torah, not a question about Islam or Judaism. You seem to be conflating religion with religious text with your (mis)reference to Monica's comment.

Comment: @CarlMasens the question is one about Jewish Law.  The answer has to be within the bounds of Jewish Law.  Halacha is the Hebrew word for 'Jewish Law'.

Comment: The presence of a particular subject in a question does not constrain the question to that particular subject.