# Children of converts to another religion

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

What's the status of the offspring of a Jewish woman who converted to another religion (knowing the woman herself nonetheless remains Jewish)? Are they still Jewish?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501). Hope to see you around!

Answer (score 3):

Someone born of a Jewish mother remains Jewish whatever they do.

See See https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/601092/jewish/Why-Is-Jewishness-Matrilineal.htm#footnoteRef1a601092

and

https://www.thoughtco.com/who-is-a-jew-2077197

Comment: The second citation is incorrect. The *examples* of nonJewish women marrying Jewish men were cases before the Torah was given at Sinai or in which the women converted before marriage.

Answer (score 2):

See [Can a Jew lose their Jewish Status?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7775/can-a-jew-lose-their-jewish-status) which explains why a Jew who tries to *convert* to another religion is still a Jew though a sinner. As a result, (see ["Am I Jewish​​​?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52891/am-i-jewish))  the child of a woman who *converts* is still Jewish, though the child of a Jewish man with a nonJewish woman is not Jewish, whether the man *converted* or not.

Answer (score 1):

A Jew remains a Jew, no matter what, even if he converts to another religion. A Jew is defined by someone who is born of a Jewish mother, or someone who converted to Judaism through a Orthodox Bais Din and a Mikveh for a woman, or a Orthodox Bais Din, Mikveh and circumcision for a man. Therefore, in your case, even though the mother converted to another religion, her children are still Jewish, because she is Jewish herself (that didn't change when she converted, whether she likes it or not). So, her children "receive all the priveleges thereof" of a full-born Jew.

(She herself, too, has all the rights as a full-born Jew, despite her conversion, if she does Teshuvah.)

The children of a Jewish man and a non-Jewish woman, however, are NOT Jewish, even if the man didn't convert out of Judaism. The mother must be Jewish to have Jewish children, this is the way Orthodox Halacha works.

Comment: In biblical times it went through the father. The rabbis changed this Torah rule. Why? No body knows.

Comment: @TurkHill The tradition of matrilineal descent goes as far back as Ezra HaSofer, see Sefer Ezra where Ezra rules the children of Jewish fathers and non-Jewish mothers are not Jewish.

Comment: yes, but prior to Ezra, there was no such rule.

Comment: @TurkHill What makes you assume that?

Comment: There is a lot of evidence and biblical evidence that matrilineal descent was a later development. The original Torah was deeply conservative (no adding, no subtracting), one’s Israelite identity was determined by one’s father’s lineage. The Torah makes it clear: מִשְׁפַּט אֶחָד יִהְיֶה לָכֶם, *כַּגֵּר כָּאֶזְרָח* יִהְיֶה כִּי אֲנִי יְהוָה אֱלֹהֵיכֶם.
“You shall have one manner of law, *as well for the stranger, as for the native-born*; for I am the YHWH your G-d.'-

Comment: @TurkHill I literally don’t see how that passage proves anything you’re trying to say.