# When, halachically, does a sect of Judaism become an independent religion?

Tags: gentiles, halacha-theory, christianity, shabbetai-tzvi

When Christianity began many followers considered themselves Jews, the same could be said for followers of Shabbtai Tzvi. I don't believe there is anyone today who would argue that a child born to Christian or [Donmeh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%B6nmeh) parents has the status of a Jew. I would like to know if there is any sort of halachic demarcation line for when a sect of Judaism would be considered a different religion such that children born to parents who are part of that sect would not be considered Jewish.

Comment: Is there halachically such a thing as a "religion"?  Actions and beliefs are allowed or not allowed, but that has nothing to do with whether someone is Jewish or not.

Comment: @Heshy if we assume then that rov Christians were Jews (vs pagans) at the outset then would you posit that all Christians today are Jews?

Comment: I don't think your rov is correct.  Maybe in the very early days, but then they managed to convert almost the entire Europe and parts of Asia, who weren't rov Jews.

Comment: @Heshy convert to... judaism? If they were all jews then the people converting would be converting into judaism, no?

Comment: No, because they didn't follow a valid conversion procedure.  Even if we're generous and assume they did baptism in a valid mikveh (I know very little about it but I guess that's possible) and accepted the only commandments they knew about, which would have been bein adam lachaveiro, there was definitely no milah and no valid Beis Din.  You need Jews who keep the mitzvos, which Christians or Sabbateans aren't.

Comment: I don't think there is ever a point where adherents to a different sect/religion officially 'lose' their Jewishness, but realistically, after a relatively short time, they'll lose a pure matrilineal descent. If a 30 generation Christian can prove Jewish Matrilineal descent, they'd be considered a Jew, and if not, they won't (in practice, if this ever comes up i.e. a family claiming without proof that they are Marrano's, there will probably be some sort of Giyur Misafek).

Comment: @Salmononius2 interesting point, if memory serves according to the gemarah (I believe kiddushin, but could be yevamot) one only needs to check a potential mates 'yichus' going back 4 generations.

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7775/759

Comment: The line that when crossed means that that sect has removed itself from Judaism appears to typically be when that sect removes itself from the Jewish public - klal Yisrael. With Christians, they were given an option: Stay in shul, pray like everyone else or not - and be removed. They chose the latter. With the Samaritans, after generations of their having mostly remained a separate nationality, it was decided that if they couldn't commit to the Jewish nationality, they had no place in the Jewish religion.

Comment: This explains also the difference between the Eastern/"Mizrachi" Karaites and the "Ashkenazi" Karaites - The former had close ties to the rabbinic Jewish communities while the latter gradually moved away from their rabbinical neighbors, until many of them actually announced that they had nothing to do with the Jews. They were not Jews, they were Karaites - a wholly separate group. It was at that point that the Ashkenazi poskim declared them to be non-Jews.

Comment: Even today there are various sects in Judaism with problematic views, including within Orthodoxy. But as they still view themselves as part of the klal, they remain so.

Comment: This is a really great question about the quantum of heresy required to make a sect non-Jewish. Certainly, accepting opposite halachic decisions on genuine issues of doubt does not make one or both sects non-Jewish, but would a sect that holds that the modern-day pig is not the same pig described in the Torah and has its rabbis rule that modern-day pigs are kosher, but otherwise appears to be orthodox, necessarily be a non-Jewish religion?

Answer (score 14):

Rav Aharon Lichtenstein zt"l wrote an essay / teshuvah titled "Brother Daniel and the Jewish Fraternity" (Judaism 12:260-280, Summer 1963). Brother Daniel was a Catholic monk who applied for Israeli citizenship under the Law of Return, since he was born Jewish. In it, Rav Lichtenstein deals with this very question.

While we generally repeat the gemara that says that once someone converted, even if they returned to their old faith, they are still Jewish. An apostate Jew is still a Jew, and his marriage valid. ([Yevamos 47b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.47b.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) As the idiom goes, "ישראל, אף על פי שחטא, ישראל הוא -- an Israelite, even though he sinned, is an Israelite."

However, there are two other gemaras. R' Assi worries about the potential validity of a marriage between a non-Jew and a Jew, because it is possible that the alleged non-Jew is actually a descendent of one of the 10 lost tribes. ([Yevamos 16b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.16b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) But the gemara concludes ([Yevamos 17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.17a.1-4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) with Shmuel's commitment to find a disproof. Apparently the 10 tribes are no longer "an Israelite, even though he sinned." Quoting Hosea, one of their last prophets who warned them ([Hosea 5:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Hosea.5.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

> "בַּה' בָּגָדוּ, כִּי-בָנִים זָרִים יָלָדוּ; עַתָּה יֹאכְלֵם חֹדֶשׁ, אֶת-חֶלְקֵיהֶם
>
> They were treacherous with Hashem, for they have begotten strange children, now shall the new moon consume them [and?] their portion."

R' Aharon cites a second gemara with this position. Rav Ami and Rav Assi ([Chullin 6a](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.6a.6-7?lang=bi)) learned that the Kusim (Samaritans) were not observing the Torah. "זזו משם עד שעשאום עובדי כוכבים גמורין - and they did not move from there until they made them [the Kusim] full-fledged gentiles.

So how is it that a backslid convert is considered still Jewish, but the 10 Lost Tribes and Samaritans are not?

Rav Aharon lists three possible resolutions:

**1)** The Rashba tones down the statement about the Kusim. He says yes, they are indeed Jewish halachically, but since the rabbinate has the power to make or break marriages, they invalidated the marriages of Samaritans, making the marriage invalid LIKE those between a Jew and a non-Jew. Similarly, the Shulchan Arukh ([YD 159:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.159.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) rules that Kusim are included in the prohibition against charging or paying interest.

**2)** The Mordechai (Hagahos Mordechai Yavamos 107) takes the opposite approach -- the validity of the marriage of the backslid convert is only as a stringency. We cannot invalidate the marriage because the husband might have thoughts of teshuvah. But if we could read minds and know that he really did return to his old faith, his Judaism would evaporate.

(I am pausing my summary of the article to note that while this is theoretically interesting, I would be hard pressed to believe the Mordechai's position is a viable ruling today for pragmatic use. Consensus seems to have retired it. Perhaps as one factor among others when a rabbi is seeking a way to let a wife remarry when her apostate husband won't give her a *get*.)

**3)** Rav Aharon rules like his wife's great-grandfather's, Rav Chaim Brisker's resolution of the apparent contradiction. The Rambam rules that the apostate's marriage is still valid (see [Hilchos Ishus 4:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Marriage.4.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) and [Hil' Issurei Bi'ah 13:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.13.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). And he writes in his commentary on the mishnah to [Niddah 7:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Niddah.7.4?lang=bi&p2=Rambam_on_Mishnah_Niddah.7.4.1&lang2=bi) that something that is in an inclosed with a Kusi's body in it is not tamei, like it would be if it were a Jewish body.

Rav Chaim (and Rav Lichtenstein) understands the Rambam as distinguishing between the cases on the grounds of core identity. The apostate who goes back to acting as he did before converting to Judaism, even in worshipping idols (or the trinity), committed what Rav Aharon calls an "apostasy of action". However, the 10 Tribes and the Kusim lost their core identity. When the person gives up their Jewish roots, Jewishness is indeed lost.

I think that gives two or maybe three valid answers to your question. (Depending if you agree to what I wrote about consensus burying the viability of ruling like the Mordekhai today.)

However, Rav Aharon Lichtenstein rules in practice like the third. Brother Daniel joined another faith community. He doesn't try to be one of the Jewish Community. So, he is not halachically Jewish.

Meanwhile, Brother Daniel may share more beliefs with Rav Aharon than would the typical Reform Rabbi -- he believes that the Torah was given to Moshe (perhaps even dictated) in the Sinai, that the Exodus really happened as told, that G-d "Spoke" to the Jews at Sinai, etc... But the Reform Rabbi did not give up his Jewish roots.

The apostate Jew who sees himself as just that -- an differently-believing *Jew*, and a member of the Jewish community -- is not obligated to convert. However, *lechatchila* (if we can, before the fact) we would require a dunk in the mikvah as a sign of commitment before counting him toward a minyan.

A baal teshuvah doesn't need to go to the mikvah before we count him toward a minyan, because typically they are not apostates in the active sense, they are products of upbringing (tinoqos shenishbu) who happened to end up believing apostasy.

But Brother Daniel, because he left the Jewish People except when there was a legal advantage to pretend otherwise, would actually need that dunking halachically, at least according to this ruling.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "jewish roots" how has the reform rabbi not given up those roots by violating rambam's 13 principles? Based on your reasoning I don't see how your conclusion regarding baale teshuva follows or how one could touch wine of an "unaffiliated" jew. I'm very confused by this answer

Comment: @rikitiki I think the point is that the conservative still calls himself a Jew. The unaffiliated still says he's a Jew or a part Jew or something. It's not like a Christian who thinks he replaced the Jew as the new chosen people.

Comment: @rikitikitembo , I used the terminology Rav Lichtenstein did. The only bit I intentionally added was an opinion about one of the options he listed but did not embrace. I opined that the the halachic process has rejected the idea that an apostate ceases to be Jewish (with caveats about having to be strict because we aren’t mind readers).

Comment: I can opine about what he meant, but then we are taling my opinion, not Rav Aharon Lichtenstein’s. I think @user6591 is correct.

Comment: @user6591 therefore Jews for Jesus are jewish? According to this logic early Christians or Sabbateans, even though they professed antinomian beliefs and (the former) were singled out by chazal in v'lamalshinim would still be considered Jewish?

Comment: @riki if they started Jewish they wouldn't stop being jewish is the point, not that what they're doing is right or that anyone who follows their ideas is Jewish. but please just read the article instead of asking R Micha for more interpretation.

Comment: @DoubleAA I took your suggestion and reread the post. The article was not linked so I'm unable to review it directly but I had asked for clarification because I could not understand the logic of the answer. There was no indication in the answer as to what Jewish roots are or why we assume the 10 tribes gave theirs up. It is still unclear to me how, based on the sources cited, RAL posits someone who identifies as Jewish (not halachicly, just socially) is considered a Jew

Comment: @rikitiki I didn't say that. I tried to preclude you saying that by mentioning that Christians think they replaced the Jew and are the new chosen nation. That is, the name Jew or Israelite doesn't mean that a person associates with Judaism. The Afrikaans in Times square who call themselves the real Israelites are not Jewish by Rabbi Lichtenstein's theory. A convert to a different religion isn't Jewish just because he calls himself a Jewish version of that religion like the J for Js. That chazzal cursed someone doesn't prove if they are Jewish or not.

Comment: @riki I googled the name of the article and the word Lichtenstein  and found https://books.google.com/books?id=_QshqTu9nGIC&pg=PA57&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @rikitiki just for the record I heard a very similar idea from Reb Dovid Feinstein. He was darshaning one of the psukim about redemption, the refers to us as with birth the term Yaakov and Yisroel. He said Yaakov is the affiliated religious Jew. Yisroel is the unaffiliated one who still calls himselfa Jew. He too gets redeemed. To punctuate the message he said the guy eating pig on yom kippur who says 'kulanu yihudim!' is included in the term Yisroel.

Comment: Remember that the nearest thing we have to a doxology doesn't "merely" make religious claims, it begins "Listen Israel". Being part of the Israelite project is the first element of what it means to be Jewish. As Ruth put it, when she chose to convert, "your nation is my nation, and your G-d is my G-d". And as many note on the words of the seder's comment about the WIcked Son "... because he excluded himself from the community, he denied the foundational [principle]."

Comment: @rikitikitembo: Using the word "Jewish" doesn't make j4j part of our community. They're a straight Baptist church. The concept is belonging to the community, not wallpapering over abandonment by using the word "Jewish", and throwing in a lot of Yiddish and traditional Ashkenazi foods.

Comment: I agree but according to the strict criteria set forth in the article one (who was born a Jew) could conceivable call themselves a Jew and do anything including encourage other Jews to abandon their faith, and their children would still be considered Jewish. this is a not-obvious extension of yisrael af al pi sh'chateh

Answer (score 0):

Dr. Lawrence Schiffman addresses this question in his book *Who Was a Jew?: Rabbinic and Halakhic Perspectives on the Jewish Christian Schism*. The answer he provides for Christianity is that it was a gradual process but there were major milestones such as the promulgation of the blessing against heretics in the amida and the banning of Jews from Jerusalem after the Bar Kochva revolt. These factors combined to make it abundantly clear to the outside world who was a Jew and who was a Christian. Jewish Christians may have persisted in smaller groups after that and a possible final demarcation would be the declaration of Christianity as the official religion of the Roman Empire.

I would speculate that similar world events helped to identify that followers of Shabbtai Tzvi were no longer considered part of Judaism after he apostatized.

Answer (score -2):

A form of worship(or even "sect" of Judaism) halachically becomes distinct from Judaism when it rejects any or all of the fundamentals of Judaism and adopts halachic practices and processes rejected by Chazal. Children born to these sects remain Jewish until they are born to a non-Jewish woman. Once they are borne from a non-Jewish woman, the child loses their status as a Jew and requires conversion, should they wish to become Jewish.

The fundamentals of Judaism have been redacted to 13 principles by the Rambam and can be found here:https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/332555/jewish/Maimonides-13-Principles-of-Faith.htm.

These are them(credit to chabad.org):

1. Belief in the existence of the Creator, who is perfect in every manner of existence and is the Primary Cause of all that exists.
2. The belief in G‑d's absolute and unparalleled unity.
3. The belief in G‑d's non-corporeality, nor that He will be affected by any physical occurrences, such as movement, or rest, or dwelling.
4. The belief in G‑d's eternity.
5. The imperative to worship G‑d exclusively and no foreign false gods.
6. The belief that G‑d communicates with man through prophecy.
7. The belief in the primacy of the prophecy of Moses our teacher.
8. The belief in the divine origin of the Torah.
9. The belief in the immutability of the Torah.
10. The belief in G‑d's omniscience and providence.
11. The belief in divine reward and retribution.
12. The belief in the arrival of the Messiah and the messianic era.
13. The belief in the resurrection of the dead.

The early catholics rejected the Torah and replaced it with a "new testament"; thus changing the Torah in violation of principle #9. They also violated principle #5.

The Tzadukim and Beitusim rejected the principle of olam haba, in violation of principles 12 & 13.

The Karaites rejected that the Torah is divine, in violation of principle #8.

The kutim worshipped a small dove, in violation of principle #5.

The Reform and Conservative movements rejected the belief in one God(or don't require it, at least), that the Torah is divine, and more. Although many of them are still Jews(for now), they marry non-Jews freely and their children and/or grandchildren are not or won't be Jewish once they will be born to a non-Jewish woman. See here for a chart based on statistics from the Pew Research center:https://www.simpletoremember.com/grandchildren/WYGBJpdf.pdf.

As with most of the above listed sects, the first generations were Jewish, but they eventually married out(demarcation/halachic line of maintaining Jewish status) and lost their status as Jews. The same will be true and is true of every religion that doesn't adhere to Judaism; they eventually marry out and bear non-Jewish children until the majority/totality of the sect becomes non-Jewish.

Comment: Why won't their grandchildren be Jewish? At least half them will be (the children of their daughters)

Comment: You don't seem to have read the entire question. "when a sect of Judaism would be considered a different religion such that children born to parents who are part of that sect would not be considered Jewish.” are you claiming the children of someone who believes God has a toenail are not Jewish?

Comment: You may want to check out Galton-Watson processes. This is the symmetrical case of course but mathematically identical. It's not hard to find where the chance of survival rises above 50%

Comment: And you should see the chart for the general case at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galton%E2%80%93Watson_process The details of the modern American dating scene and birth rate are fundamentally flukes. Other heretical groups will surely reproduce faster even above replacement.

Comment: The question asks whether/when following other religions affects Jewish status (specifically of children born into it).  Even atheists born of Jewish mothers are Jewish, and they don't follow all 13 principles either, so somewhere there's apparently a *halachic* line.  Could you address that more directly?  Right now I'm having trouble seeing how this answers the question.  (BTW, your claim about R and C not believing in one god is not only incorrect but needlessly provocative.)

Comment: Not requiring is not the same as rejecting, which was your claim. I'm not sure the Orthodox make *belief* demands on their members, either; I mean, there is the rabbinic literature shared by *everybody*, like the Rambam, but I've never heard of anybody screening people on beliefs before letting them join a synagogue, for example. And belief in one god is clearly normative in R & C if you look at their siddurim, responsa, etc. But all of that is a tangent, one I only brought up because your claim is provocative and doesn't serve your argument at all. I'd hoped you would see that and remove it.

Comment: The question does not seem to be when do the adherents of a sect lose their * Jewish status*. That is answered by the *who is a Jew* questions as any Jew who follows a different religion is still Jewish (though a sinner). The question seems to be when does the sect (as a group) cross the line from a sect to a different religion.

Comment: I'll just note as well that there are no sources at all in this post (other than one to identify each of the 13 principles)

Comment: Christians wouldn't disagree with any of those 13 points except for 7. And Christians still believe Moses is of highest importance.

Comment: @curiousdannii They definitely disagree with 3 and 9 and probably how-Judaism-construes-2.

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe 3 (but only after the incarnation, and only for one person of the godhead, though that the incarnation is possible might be enough to say that we reject it as Judiasm would construe it). You're right about 2 in that we'd interpret such a statement differently.  On the whole I think most Christians would uphold 9. The question is its applicability.