# Jewish status as dependent on righteous behaviour

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, gentiles, sin

Are there any sources which suggest that somebody's Jewish status is dependent on their refraining from wrongdoing? Obviously a cherem can limit someone's involvement in the community in response to wrongdoing. But are there any texts suggesting that someone can altogether be regarded as not Jewish if they engage in [perhaps specified] wrongful conduct?

(The answer may well be 'no'. Just curious.)

Comment: There’s halachos of a mumar that affect some laws but not his overall Jewish status

Comment: what about for a convert? https://etzion.org.il/en/halakha/yoreh-deah/topics-yoreh-deah/nullification-conversion

Comment: @Chatzkel There are some sources like that, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98082/759

Comment: why was this closed? The answer is, yes. An atheistic Jew may still be a Jew in the eyes of the community but he is no longer a Jew in the eyes of God.